# Using HashMap with custom object in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to use the following code to create `HashMap` of custom Objects.

```
public static void test() {
    programStats ps = new programStats();
    programStats ps1 = new programStats();
    List<programStats> psList = new LinkedList<programStats>();

    ps.progName = "test1";  
    ps1.progName= "Test11";

    psList.clear();
    psList.add(ps);

    Map<String,List<programStats>> d = new HashMap<String, List<programStats>>();
    d.put("Test1", psList);

    psList.add(ps1);
    for (programStats p : d.get("Test1")) {
        System.out.println(p.progName);
    }
```

```
class  programStats {
        public static String progName, module;
        public static int min, max,  mean,  mid, count;
        public static List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();;
}
```

I have noticed that when I'm setting the value to `ps1`, the value of `ps` is changing too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All your fields are `static`, which means there will be one field per **class**, but you want non-static ones (i.e. just leave the `static` out) to have one field per **instance**.

Comment: Joachim, You are right!! I did not see that !!! I'm stuck on this for 4 hours now... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the members of your `programStats` class are `static`, meaning they belong to the **class**, not a specific **instance**.
So, regardless of which instance you use to modify them, those values would be visible via any instance. You should change them to instance members:

```java
class  programStats {
    // Note: The member are no longer static:
    public String progName, module;
    public int min, max,  mean,  mid, count;
    public List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```